# Calling to a different stimuli lists

Tags: psychopy

I need to call to a different column with the stimuli depending on a previous given response. I.e. age

- ask for age
- if age = X --> choose a certain stimuli column (or a certain xlsx file)

What would be the basic procedure to do this. I am new in Psychopy.

Thanks a lot
Elena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a field for age to the experiment info dialog box shown at the beginning of each session. Then you can refer to that value later in code as `expInfo['age']`.

Let's say you have two columns in your conditions file, labelled `list_A` and `list_B`, and you want to use either of those to put values into a text stimulus. In that text stimulus, put a variable called something like `$text_list`. Then in a code component, in the "begin routine" tab, put something like this:

```
if expInfo['age'] > 30:
    text_list = list_A
else:
    text_list = list_B
```

The same principles apply if you want to select between .xlsx files. Put a variable name in the conditions file file field of the loop dialog, and in some routine *prior* to the loop, set that variable to contain the desired filename.

Comment: Cheers. If so, could you mark the answer as "accepted"? The big green tick helps future readers know the solution worked.

Comment: Sure :). I am new in this stack overflow system as well…thanks again.